# Flash redundant code copy to microcontroller flash memory

Tags: c++, linker, microcontroller, flash-memory

I am working on a satellite-based project and part of the project is to store a redundant copy of the program code in flash memory. I have looked everywhere and found nothing. Is there anyway to use the c++ linker to place code copies in two areas of memory? I have limited ken of linker code. Is there maybe a different way to do this if not with the linker other than using a startup routine when the microcontroller initially boots up after flashing?

Just to be clear: there will be an executable version of the code in one region of the flash memory and a copy and, if possible, non-executable version of the code in another region of the flash memory. The program code includes all interrupt vectors. I have already modified the linker code to divide the flash memory into the segments I want.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Do you have access the the flash writing commands while your program is running, in which case your program could make the copy at first startup? Or is the flash only writeable by external means?

Comment: I have complete access to the memory at any time. I was looking for an initial flashing procedure since the microcontroller may experience PORs (power-on resets) or full power cycles due to the nature of my project; an initial power-up or reset routine will require taking up more flash memory for code and storage of a variable.

Comment: What is the purpose of the redundant copy?  Would you execute it from its redundant location if the original is corrupt?  Or do you just want an identical copy to compare with the original or to copy to the original location when necessary?  What is your microcontroller and tool chain?

Comment: The redundant copy will be used to refresh the program code should it become corrupt. CRCs will be used to check if the code is corrupt. I am using an MSP430 and the custom TI toolchain.

Comment: @etienz  Refresh how exactly?  How do you detect corruption? What if the two codebases differ because the **backup** is the corrupt one?  Electrically, how will you self-flash from flash?  What code will copy the code to the other code, and using what interface?  Have you thought about all these things?  And surely you're using a radiation-hardened part?

Comment: @TomServo The point of the whole design is to not use expensive radiation-hardened components in a low cost, university satellite. There will be two microcontrollers setup the exact same that can interface with one another. There will be two copies of the code and a CRC hashsum of the code in the flash. The code won't be compared to it's copy but rather the CRC stored in flash. It's not entirely my design but it is a university project so it's definitely legitimate.

Comment: @etienz  I see, fair enough.  It may be helpful for people who might have answers if you would include these design constraints/requirements into your original question.  I'm guessing it will raise your odds of getting a good answer.

Answer (score 0):

IMHO if you are trying to protect your system this way (double instance) because you are expecting bit flips due to the radiation in space, then your chances of a system surviving longer than around 10x the estimated mean time between incidents (radiation changing a bit) are rather slim. Checksum error detection is for the 1 defect in 10^6 samples in mass production devices with fail-silent requirements. It is unsuited for fail-active systems where the risk vs cost of the system fits on a more or less 4 point coordiante system.